# How to show native view in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

In flutter, how can we show the native views via method channel?. I had gone through these articles of platform views:

1. https://60devs.com/how-to-add-native-code-to-flutter-app-using-platform-views-android.html
2. https://itnext.io/using-native-ui-in-flutter-with-platformview-6b9d46265332

These tutorials are good if you want to communicate (send and receive data) between flutter and android/ios.

But I want to show my already built android activity on the flutter side. But still, I am not able to understand; how and where I will link my XML layout on the native android side.
if anyone can help me with code, it will be beneficial for everybody. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party. To answer your question, There is no way you can display the native view with the MethodChannel/EventChannel since this referred to transferring data between the platforms.
If I am not wrong what you are looking for is PlatformView. Refer to this tutorial. [Hosting native vIew in Flutter.](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-platformview-how-to-create-flutter-widgets-from-native-views-366e378115b6)

Answer (score -1):

You can import android activity to flutter by using methodChannel with startActivity method.